# Convert Angular (javascript) expression into object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Could you tell me how to convert the below mentioned angular dropdown box expression into object array ? B'cos I have to use the object array instead of angular expression with drop down directive mentioned below.Thanks in advance.

```
a.id as a.num + ', '+ a.townName for a in vm.schoolDistricts
```

This is the directive : [Typeahead Dropdown](https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.typeaheadDropdown)

Comment: Inside an angular expression you can also specify a method that can be called to retrieve the values. Please try if that works

Comment: @M22an The problem here is above mentioned directive doesn't accept the angular expressions.That's why I need to convert above expression into object array where above directive can use it.Here is the directive : https://github.com/spongessuck/gm.typeaheadDropdown

Comment: From the docs it looks like you need to add another field in your collection `schoolDistricts` for example `typeAheadContent` and provide that in the config's `optionlabel`.

Comment: @M22an How can I do that ? On the above expression where `vm.schoolDistricts` is the collection of objects.I can use it with angular drop down as shown below : `<select ng-model="vm.property.schoolDistrictId" class="form-control" 
ng-options="a.id as a.num + ', '+ a.townName for a in vm.schoolDistricts" 
required>
       <option value="" disabled="">-- Select a School District --</option>
</select>`

Comment: @M22an But the same expression doesn't work with the above directive.That is the issue.

Comment: What I mean is that if you had an equivalent of `a.id as a.num + ', '+ a.townName` in `vm.schoolDistricts` then that might work, but yes this directive has a big limitation here and can be requested as a feature add in the repo.

Comment: now in this directive you can't use expression, because in template it use hardcode: `typeahead="op[config.optionLabel] for op in options` so just one possible solution, as say @M22an, add to objects that contains in `vm.schoolDistricts` property like `label` init it `obj.label = obj.num + ', '+ obj.townName` and use it as label

Comment: @M22an Could you put that as an answer ? Unfortunately it's not clear what you're saying.But if you can put that as an answer with bit details then I can try that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As @Grundy and I pointed out in the comments, this directive can only take any of the properties from your array. So in order to overcome this you can include the expression you want

`a.num + ', '+ a.townName`

in each array element.

If your current array looks something like,

```
schoolDistrict = [{name:"ABC", value: "ABCVal", num: "123", townName: "myTown"}, ....]
```

then it needs to change to something like,

```
schoolDistrict = [{name:"ABC", value: "ABCVal", num: "123", townName: "myTown", typeAheadLabel:"123, myTown"}, ....]
```

With this you would be able to use typeAheadLabel in the config like,

```
$scope.config = {
        modelLabel:'districts',
        optionLabel:'typeAheadLabel'
    };
```

In the view you can use something like,

```
<typeahead-dropdownng-model="vm.property.schoolDistrictId" class="form-control" 
      options="vm.schoolDistricts" config="config" required> 
<option value="" disabled="">-- Select a School District --</option> </typeahead-dropdown>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'll try that and let you know :)